# Azure Iot Hub To Esp-32 (Running Mongoose OS)

Tags: azure, mongoose, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub, mongoose-os

I’ve been trying for hours to find a way to receive messages on my esp running Mongoose OS from the Azure IoT Hub, my goals is to trigger some code(or function) from the Azure IoT Hub(using Functions apps, but I’ll figure this out later).

How can I connect these?

I was thinking of using MQTT but I can’t find any documentation on how to do this.
Thank you very much!

Comment: If you want to use MQTT directly (without using any of the device SDKs), have you read through this article? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support#receiving-cloud-to-device-messages

Comment: Yes, I've seen that article, I have cloud-to-device messages working from the IoT-Hub to my ESP32, the only thing I'm struggling with is sending a MQTT message from Function Apps to the IoT Hub

Comment: ok. I added an answer for that below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send messages from the cloud via the IoT Hub to devices, you do not use the MQTT protocol. Instead you (usually) use the IoT Hub *Service* SDK. See here for an example how to do this in C#:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-c2d#send-a-cloud-to-device-message

There are also SDKs for other languages. If you don't want to use any of the SDKs, you could also call the REST API of the IoT Hub's service side.

Here is also an example that shows how to do this in an Azure Function (just first google result): https://gist.github.com/jsturtevant/1d383c682d0d2c6422218bac4b7f5c8d#file-run-csx

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for taking the time to respond, I got it working.
In Mongoose OS is use this code to subscribe to the IoT hub messages:

```
MQTT.sub('devices/' + Cfg.get('device.id') + '/messages/devicebound/#', function(conn, topic, msg) {
 print('Topic:', topic, 'message:', msg);
}, null);
```

And in Azure Functions I use a HTTP trigger with the following code:

```
var connnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["aConnectionString"];

var serviceClient = ServiceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connnectionString);

var commandMessage = new Message(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"Message!"));

await serviceClient.SendAsync("esp32_8965FC", commandMessage);
```